# Multy-filter page with transitions - Isotope & Quicksand JS problems

Tags: javascript, filter

(note: edited since I've just realized the question are somehow correlated, at least in my mind!)

I want to create a multi-filter page in which the result will be animated...
I'm trying with 2 different plugin (quicksand and Isotope) and with both solution I'm having problems...

---ISOTOPE--- (original)

With Isotope I need to filter data based on active class, or based on IDs of filters, which I've already stored in JS, does anyone know how can I do that?

I set up a page with 2 different filter like 'color' (red, blue, orange...) and 'type' (square, round...)
I already have a Javascript that assign class active to the 2 filtering lu based on selection,  if all color are selected shift the 'active' class to 'all', and more than one sub-filter can be activated. And this also save the list of the id of the active li items in a string for color filter and another string for shape filter

I also already set up the page like the combination filter Isotope demo at this link: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/combination-filters.html and it is working fine but doesn't allow to select more than one sub-filter at the same time.

I saw the demo at this link http://fiddle.jshell.net/desandro/JB45z/ with filtering combination, but it is based on radio button that I'd like to avoid.

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is easy or not... is like, how to tell to Isotope to filter based on the sub-filter that have active class or based on the sum of the li with the ID saved in my two string?

Thanks for any help, as you can easily understand I'm not skilled in js at all and english is not my first language!

--- QUICKSAND --- (edited)

I've just realized that I didn't explain why I stored the IDs of the selected items in the js string. And this is also about the different js question.

I was trying to set up the same system with Quicksand instead of Isotope.

But since quicksand need to have a starting li and a destination li to display the animation I set up the js to pass an array to a different temporary php page that use the array to display a destination li.

All until here is working fine but I'm not able to get back the li data in the original page to let Quicksand perform the animation. The last part of my js appear to have problems that I'm not able to fix (too many days trying with no success), the last part of the js is:

```
$.post( 'destination_li_filtered.php', { 
 colorString, 
 shapeString, 
 $('#ids').attr('val') 
}, 
function(data) { // should contains the resulting data from the request (?)
 $('.list').quicksand( $(data).find('li'), 
 { adjustHeight: 'auto' }, 
 function() { 
 callbackCode(); 
} 
);
e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

the external page destination-li-filtered is displaying the results but the original page is not able to take back the data...

Obviously I need to set op the page with isotope or quicksand, not both.

but I'm also wondering witch is the best plugin to display 100's of results with about 20 filters (without considering the combinations). And of course, which is the easiest to use!

Answer (score 0):

You should see the radio button and the change in view as separate things.

It's a common misconception that you should store all your state in the DOM (ie. which checkbox is checked). The DOM is a *view*, you don't keep state in a *view*.

You should have a state that lives in your JavaScript.

Like:

```
var state = "all_selected"; // green, red, blue
```

Then, when you check the radio button, it will set the appropriate state and update the list (show/hide elements based on state).

This allows you to make any control you want, be it a radio button, a checkbox or something completely custom.

Comment: Hi Frits, many thanks for your answer!
but I have to ask you some clarification on that...

I now have stored in Javascript, 2 String, inside each string I have the value of the ID of the filter I need to use (based on user selection)
I can use this directly in the Isotope script?
or I need first to transform this from the IDs to the corresponding data-filter-value?

Comment: sorry, i've just understood your meaning now...
so i need to write something like:
#1 for all the the 'li a' items that have class active, take the class and put in a String colorClassString (same w/TypeClassString)
OR #1a for the 'li a' with ID corresponding to the one I've stored in my string, give me the class and put in a colorClassString (same w/TypeClassString)
#2 do some operation to get only the class I need (because if i've active filter on color:all and type:square and I just put together all the classes it will display all the items again, right?

Comment: #3 put the resulting String in the call to Isotope
Is this right? sorry but it takes me a lot of time to understand what and how to do, and is already loooong time i'm working on this! any idea (or better, time to tell me ;-) how to write that in js?